# Prove that $aX: \Omega \rightarrow \Bbb R$, $\omega \rightarrow aX(\omega)$, for a $\in \Bbb R$, is a random variable

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mathscr P)$ be a probability space and $X, Y : \Omega \rightarrow \Bbb R$ random variables. Prove that

$aX: \Omega \rightarrow \Bbb R$, $\omega \rightarrow aX(\omega)$, for a $\in \Bbb R$,

is a random variable.

We got to know this new way of proving a certain statement before:

If $P$ is a property that every subset of $\Omega$ can possess, and if

i) Every $E \in \mathscr M$ (which is a subset of the power series of $\Omega$) possesses $P;$

ii) The set $\Sigma' := \{E \subset \Omega : E$ possesses $P\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

is true, then every element of $\Sigma = \langle \mathscr M \rangle^{\sigma} \subset \Sigma'$ possess the property $P$ too.

Furthermore, I know that $X$ is a random variable iff $X^{-1}([b, \infty[) \in \Sigma$ for every $b \in \Bbb R.$ In order to use the proof scheme above, I choose $\mathscr M$ to be the set of all sets $[b, \infty[$ and note that $\mathscr M$ generates the $\sigma$-algebra of the borel sets.

For the property $P$, we choose

$(aX)^{-1} ([b, \infty[) \in \Sigma$ for b $\in \Bbb R. $

So the property is that every half-open intervall has to possess a pre-image in $\Sigma$. This would make the function measurable, thus, make it a random variable.

But I'm stuck at this very step. I know that $X$ is a random variable, thus, the property holds for every half-open interval when we only take a look at $X$, but how do I have to deal with the real factor $a \in \Bbb R$ here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you said, $X$ is a random variable if $X^{-1}([b,\infty[)\in\Sigma$, for all $b\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now assume $a>0$ (the case a<0 is similar, the case $a=0$ is trivial). Given any $b\in\mathbb{R}$, note that $(aX)^{-1}([b,\infty[) = \{\omega\in\Omega: \ b\leq aX(\omega)<\infty \} = \{\omega\in\Omega: \ \frac{b}{a}\leq X(\omega)<\infty \} = X^{-1}([\frac{b}{a},\infty[)\in\Sigma$. This proves $aX$ is a random variable.

Comment: Thank you very much! Does this work the same for the sum of two random variables $X, Y$? Something like: $(X + Y)^{-1}([b, \infty[) = \{\omega\in\Omega: \ b\leq X(\omega) + Y(\omega)<\infty \} = \{\omega\in\Omega: \ b - Y(\omega) \leq X(\omega) <\infty \} =$ $X^{-1}[b - Y(\omega), \infty[)$?

Comment: The idea is the same, you want to write your set (which you don't know it's in $\Sigma$ ) as a set you know it's in $\Sigma$. But you have always to be careful.

Comment: So the way I noted it should work then?

Comment: Your way doesn't make sense. $\omega$ is not fixed so it can't appear in your last expression. I suggest you work more the definitions and some more simple examples before attacking this problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Big Hint**

$$\{aX<x\}=\begin{cases}\{X<\frac{x}{a}\}&a>0\\ \{X\leq\frac{x}{a}\}^c& a<0\end{cases}$$